# "I", "We", or Neither in code documentation

Tags: documentation

I find myself writing (hopefully) helpful comments in code (C++) documentation of the type:

```
The reason we are doing this is...
```

The reason I use "we" instead of "I" is because I do a lot of academic writing where "we" is often preferred.

So here's the question. Is there a good reason to prefer one over the other in documenting code:

1. **Use "We":** The reason we are doing this is...
2. **Use "I":** The reason I am doing this is...
3. **Use my name:** The reason `[my name]` did this is...
4. **Passive voice:** The reason this was done is...
5. **Neither:** Do this because...

I choose #1 because I'm used to writing that way, but documentation is not for the writer, it's for the reader, so I'm wondering if adding the developer name is helpful or if that just adds yet another thing that needs to be changed when maintaining the code.

Comment: I think it's down to personal preference. I don't see any reason why one would be more clear than the other in general.

Comment: How about #5: "When in the course of human events..." ;)

Comment: "Four score and seven seconds ago our forefathers did learn that the foo must be barred least our forces be overcome with NULL"

Comment: Strongly related on English.SE:  [Why do programmers always use 'we' when really they mean 'me' or 'you'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105256/why-do-programmers-always-use-we-when-really-they-mean-me-or-you) (Which was, unfortunately, closed)

Comment: Why don't say `This code was written like this because...`? (Passive voice)

Comment: @AlvinWong Passive voice is frowned upon. The reason why is unclear to me, since it eliminates the "you"/"me"/"we" problem that authors of instructions face. EDIT: However, in commits and API comments I generally write in shorter form.

Comment: @Matt The fact that there is a commit implies "The code was written like this because <foo>" where <foo> is what should go in the commit message, without the extra wasted space.

Comment: Just to address the #5 you added: I'd say that's still three words too many.  Even if "this" is a description of what the code is doing, it's still irrelevant because A) the code should be readable enough to show what it's doing without needed a comment, and B) the code could change, leaving the comment outdated and confusing.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I'd go with:

#6. **Declarative:** ...

Rather than say "The reason this was done is because each Foo must have a Bar", just say "Each Foo must have a Bar".  Make the comment into an active statement of the reason, rather than a passive one. It's generally a better writing style overall, better fits the nature of code (which *does* something), and the `the reason this was done` phrase adds no information whatsoever.  It also avoids exactly the problem you're encountering.

Comment: would you mind elaborating a bit on why would you do that? Without an explanation, this answer looks more like a bare opinion, somewhat conflicting with [back it up guidelines](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/772/31260): _'...Opinion isn’t all bad, so long as it’s backed up with something other than “because I’m an expert”, or “because I said so”, or “just because”. Use your specific experiences to back up your opinions, as above, or point to some research you’ve done on the web or elsewhere that provides evidence to support your claims...'_

Comment: @gnat "The reason this was done" doesn't add anything to the explanation. Comments should contain just enough text to get the point across and no more. Leave off the niceties, preambles, and other filler text.

Comment: @gnat - I actually had just finished adding more when I saw your comment.

Comment: @DavidHarkness - Good point. Edited that in.

Comment: +1 This is how I do it.  On occasion I used "I" or "We", then later when I read the comment it just didn't "feel" right.

Comment: I think my example was too simplistic, because indeed "the reason this was done" doesn't add anything. But there are cases when a tricky situation requires some explanation, and in that case, I find it more natural to use "we" or "I", just as I used "I" several times in this comment. But I think your answer is clear in spirit: "declarative" suggests: use the least amount of words that get the point across clearly.

Comment: @LexFridman If the commit is tricky enough to require a "why" explanation, that belongs in a comment next to the tricky code, not disconnected in the commit message.  [Comments should be used for "why", not "what"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/13/27881)

Comment: +1 With regards to brevity and conciseness, declarative is also the best choice.

Comment: I read `//` as `because` in most cases.

Comment: +1 @DavidHarkness - "just say" is the reason. If only we could close questions and answers that are too long.

Answer (score 24):

I prefer neither, and actually would leave off that introductory phrase altogether and just get to the point.  I also try to avoid just saying "this" because it leaves no way to tell if the comment is in sync with the code.  In other words, instead of:

```
// The reason this was done is to prevent null pointer exceptions later on.
```

I would say:

```
// Frobnicate the widget first so foo can never be null.
```

The fact you're adding a comment at all implies you are stating a reason, so you don't need to redundantly tell people you're explaining the reason.  Just make the reason as specific as possible, so they know as clearly as possible how to maintain that code later on.

Answer (score 4):

In C# (and in most documentation tools in other languages) there is a difference between documentation and in-line commentary. My personal opinion is that you should always use formal, declarative-style comments as *Bobson* and others suggest in the documentation of a class or member, but within the code, there's nothing wrong with being less formal. In fact, sometimes an informal comment is *more* effective at explaining why something is being don than a full exposition in formal English.

Here's a sample which I think illustrates the point.

```
/// <summary>
/// Takes data from the remote client and stores it in the database.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="data">The data to store.</param>
public void StoreData(ComplexObject data)
{
    // Don't take candy from strangers
    ComplexObject safeData = SanitizeData(data);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Side note: `SanitizeData` should return a `SafeComplexObject`. ;)

Comment: I agree, but I prefer literal (rather than metaphorical) comments, especially if there may be developers from different language backgrounds.

Answer (score 2):

Another idea to consider would be a well crafted unit test that demonstrates why the code works the way it does in place of writing a descriptive comment. This has a couple benefits over writing comments:

1. Comments do not always change when the code is changed which can lead to confusion later on.
2. Units tests give the maintainer a easy way to play with the code. Learning a new codebase can be a lot easier if you have individual units that you can break to observe what changes.

Even though this avenue requires more work up front, unit testing can be an excellent form of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Good comments are hard to write, and even the best comments are often hard to read and comprehend. If your comment is concise enough for me to absorb and precise enough to convey what I need to know about the code, it doesn't make me any difference what pronouns you use.

I would hate to discourage somebody from commenting their code because they're concerned about the case, tense, and person of their pronouns.

Comment: Let me clarify: for comments that will become part of formal documentation, a more formal tone is appropriate, and "I" and "we" are best avoided. What I had in mind with this answer was the occasional explanatory comment, for example when you've done something that will look wrong to the next guy. In those cases, where only people who work in the same code base will ever see it, I say do whatever will convey your meaning most clearly, even it it's `I wrote the code this way because...` or `what we really need here is...`. In *those* cases, a clear comment is more important than a strict style.

Answer (score 1):

> The reason I use "we" instead of "I" is because I do a lot of academic writing where "we" is often preferred.

It is a bad style, even for academic papers, unless you are trying to hide who actually decided that exact point.

As for your specific question : I wouldn't leave such comment, unless it starts with :

```
// TODO: clean this up, ...
```

or unless it explains something very important, that might not be so clear from the code. In that case, make the comment as brief as possible.